# ios: detect app was started by tapping message in notification center

Tags: ios

Is there a way to know if the app was started by tapping message in notification center?

I want to make some calls to server only if the app is started by tapping on a message in notification center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method of the application delegate, you will receive the notification information in the `launchOptions` dictionary. That way you could get to know that the app was launched from the notification tray.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' gets called only when app is first started. It is not being called when it comes to foreground from background. How can we detect when app is coming out of background ?

Comment: As @Janak Nirmal suggested, that could be done in the `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //Application did receive push notification. Do whatever you want to do
}` method.

Comment: well the problem with 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' is that I'm unable to detect if the message came directly from APNS or via 'Notification Center'.

Comment: Also, you could check the App number badge. If it's not zero, that means you have pending notification.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can find application launching reason in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// keys can be UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey

NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if(notificationPayload)
{
    // application launch because of notification
    // do some stuff here
}

return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle push notification like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *pushNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (pushNotification) {
        //Application did started by clicking push notification. Do whatever you want to do
    }

  ....//Your rest code
  ....
}
```

Some times application is in active state and still we want to handle push notification than below method will be called

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //Application did receive push notification. Do whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //Application did receive push notification. Do whatever you want to do
} Is also called when the application is in the background state, and has resigned activity. Those are extreme edge cases no one is mentioning here.

Comment: This is something new you are telling but [APPLE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:) says "it is called only when your app is running"

Comment: The application is running up until termination.... It's the same functionality provided by application:didReceiveLocalNotification:

Comment: I am really not getting you what you are trying to say here. Please elaborate more on this.