# Distinguishing if the app was launched from a remote notification or by clicking on the app icon

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I have an application which receives remote notifications. When the application is running in background, I can bring the application to foreground in two ways:
1. By clicking on the notification in the notification center.
2. By clicking on the application icon on the Home Screen of iPad.

I understand that in both cases, applicationDidBecomeActive: will be called.
I want to distinguish between the above two cases. When it is case 1, I want to open one screen and for case 2, I want to open a completely different screen and so this distinction is imperative for me. I would appreciate if anyone can help me in this regard!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897261/ios-detect-app-was-started-by-tapping-message-in-notification-center

Comment: @Ilario The question pointed out as the original is about the identifying if the application was "launched" by clicking on the notification. What I have asked is about bringing the application to foreground. Hence this is not a duplicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is launched by a push notification it will first call:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //Application did receive push notification. Do whatever you want to do
}
```

in the app delegate. `applicationDidBecomeActive` will be called afterwards.

When clicking the app icon it will either be launched via `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if the app is not already open in the multitasking menu. Or again `applicationDidBecomeActive` if it is already active.

Comment: Are you sure about didReceiveRemoteNotification being called first? (before either didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or applicationDidBecomeActive) Is there any oficial documentation source indicating this?

Comment: @HugoAllexisCardona Its been some time since i've looked at this, its been deprecated since iOS 10. I think if `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called, the notification is included in the options. Else if the app is running it will come in via `didRecieveRemoteNotification`. See the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application?language=objc